# Can't get my meteor app to run on iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, meteor

My app runs fine on an iOS simulator, but when I try to use `meteor run ios-device` in terminal, this is what I get:

```
raress-MacBook-Pro:To Dos rares$ meteor run ios-device
WARNING: You are testing your app on a remote device.For the mobile app to be
     able to connect to the local server, make sure your device is on the
     same network, and that the network configuration allows clients to
     talk to each other (no client isolation).
[[[[[ ~/To Dos ]]]]]                          

=> Started proxy.                             

Could not open your project in Xcode.         
Try running again with the --verbose option.  
Instructions for running your app on an iOS device:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-run-your-app-on-an-iOS-device
```

Comment: well I haven't tested this meteor , but the warning is visible that your device  is not connected to that network you are using on your macbook

Answer (score 1):

Try deploying your app to a server and then running your Meteor app with the --server flag. This allows the app running locally on iOS to access your server.

```
meteor deploy myapp
```

Then

```
meteor run ios-device --mobile-server http://<app-server>
```

Then I would suggest following the short guide here for connecting your iOS device using XCode... https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/How-to-run-your-app-on-an-iOS-device

Differential also has an awesome resource on this. https://github.com/Differential/meteor-mobile-cookbook/blob/master/iOS/Building.md